# What are the options for a prepaid SIM card in Paris?

Tags: france, cellphones, paris

What are the options for a prepaid SIM card in Paris?

- Data service is not necessary, only voice.
- I live in the US and I need to know the phone number for the SIM card before the trip.

Comment: Have you checked out the suggestions in the [other question on French pre-pay mobile phones](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8642/can-i-buy-a-prepaid-mobile-data-plan-while-on-route-in-france?rq=1)? Can you clarify how your question differs from that?