# Can I buy pre-paid data plan in France for 4 weeks, without speaking French?

Tags: france, cellphones, language-barrier

I am going to France (with a car) for just over 3 weeks. Is it possible to buy a pre-paid SIM card with Internet (around 500MB - 1GB), so I can use it with my phone? An important complication is that I don't speak French, so I am not able to register the SIM over the phone (unless there is an option to do it in English).

This question seems relevant:
[Can I buy a prepaid mobile data plan while on route in France?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8642/can-i-buy-a-prepaid-mobile-data-plan-while-on-route-in-france/10681#10681)

But the FrenchConnection website doesn't work and other answers seem to either be out of date (looking at the comments) or refer to websites in French.

Comment: There should be an option to do it via SMS or the Sim Services in your phone, try using that. I did this on SFR whereas some friends did it with Orange. Also, both operators offer a 3G plan with AFAIR unlimited data for about 20-30 EUR.

Answer (score 6):

I had to do the same thing. I just walked into a couple of cell phone stores in Paris - Vodafone etc and asked a young person (many of them speak English) for a prepaid SIM card that included 1GB of data. Ask them to set it up for you. English wasn't perfect but it worked. 
99% of international airports have cell phone stores and more often than not have English speaking customer service reps too.

Answer (score 2):

I actually ended up buying the sim card from LEBARA [on Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Lebara-French-FRANCE-Preloaded-credit/dp/B00FRILROI/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1409569309&sr=8-1&keywords=lebara%20french%20sim%20card) (I am not affiliated with the seller nor Lebara compary in any way). Despite what says on the package, you CAN activate it from outside of France. It was a rather easy procedure using the internet, you can also top up and buy some Internet and/or voice bundles on their website. There is an English version of the website, which made it possible in my case. The website was a bit choppy, but there is a helpful option to solve any issues over chat (again in English).

The main benefit of this option is that you have a fully activated, working SIM with all the MB you need the second you enter France. It is possible to get the same SIM card (probably cheaper) when you are in France.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider Lyca Mobile
http://www.lycamobile.fr/en/offers-mobile-internet

It is not a prepaid plan (I do know they had special deals of 10 euro for 1000 mb for 30 days). However I notice that promo is not available right now. But you can get 1 mb for 9 cents.

It is quite much but the good thing is that they offer english support. All you need is the French Lyca simcard and buy 10 euros of load.

I hope this might help.