# What's the best SIM card for France, with long validity and no hidden fees?

Tags: france, cellphones

What's the best SIM card for France, with long validity and no hidden fees? And preferably cheap to access from other countries. I come to Europe for some months every year and wish to have continuity of the phone number and confidence regarding the expenditure. Two years ago I bought a Lebara Sim and put lots of Euros on it as they said it would not expire in that case. when I returned a few months later I found they had stolen my money and de-activated the sim card.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: that's horrible you had a bad experience w/ lebara.  i have never had an experience like that and usually recommend them. i'm sorry to hear it.

Comment: How many are "few" months? Some carriers might offer longer-lived SIM cards but I don't think there are any that would keep your number active indefinitely if you don't do anything (either top up or spend credit or at the very least connect to their network). +1 to the question in any case.

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8642/can-i-buy-a-prepaid-mobile-data-plan-while-on-route-in-france?rq=1 might be relevant,

Answer (score 1):

Lebara is sometimes tricky due to some 3G thing depending on your model. If you are open to Vodafone and Orange, even though they are more expensive, maybe they would be a solution...